# How to create a foreground window to display extra content in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope to click "Upload Files" lable to display a foreground windows which include extra content, Submit and Close buttons in a html web page.

I write the following code, but it's ugly, and orginal UI is damaged when the   is shown.

Is there a good way to do that? or a good control can do that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>WiFi File Transfer</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <script src="js/jquery1.10.2.min.js?isassets=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="js/user.js?isassets=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

      $("#UploadWindows").hide();

      $("#UploadFile").click(function() {
        $("#UploadWindows").show();
      });

      $("#Close").click(function() {
        $("#UploadWindows").hide();
      });

    });
  </script>


</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

    <div id="header">
      <a href="#">

        <span id="UploadFile">Upload Files</span>
      </a>

    </div>


    <div id="UploadWindows">

      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        Please select files to upload <br />

        <input type="file" name="myupload" multiple="multiple" />

        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Files" />
        <br />

        <span id="Close">Close</span>

      </form>

    </div>


    <div id="Div1">
      Other Content!
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

BTW, I think the edit popup window of stackoverflow  is very good, I don't know if there is simple way do to it.

[image]

Comment: you mean a `modal dialog`. try to google `github modal dialog window`

Comment: Thanks! I need to Post selected files to server side when I click Submit button in the window, can a modal dialog do that?

Comment: it has nothing to do with HTML or CSS. if you want to post data to the server, just write some JS which posts it. if that data is file(s) from the html input, then goolge "javascript submit files to server". first results are good.

Comment: I need a nice button instead of standard  button <input type="file" name="myupload" multiple="multiple" />

Comment: And more, I need to show user more information when they select files to upload, so I need a new foreground window which don't damage orignal UI .

Comment: try this: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html this is a library for making nice web components quickly. seems like you need somebody to actually build the whole thing for you :)